# How to show or hide the heading in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i need to hide the text once i click on add button and the form should be displayed.Here is my code.

```
<h2 style="font-size: 2em; margin-bottom: 0.75em; margin-left: -1%;">Specify Co-Owners for self occupied property</h2>
<div class="last" style="margin-right: 0; padding-right: 0;">
    <div class="last" style="width: 710px;">
        <p class="narrate quiet" style="margin-left: 2%; width: 100%;margin-bottom: 0.75em;"> <b>Would you like to add Co-owner? </b></p>
    </div>
</div>

//Here is add button and go back button if i click in this add button form should be displayed else t should show the same text.//

<div class="span-12 last mt10" style="margin-top:-3%;margin-left:2%;">
    <a class="large awesome oranges"  >Add a property Co-owner</a>
</div>
<div class="span-12 last mt10" style="margin-top:-3%;margin-left:51%;">
    <a class="large awesome orange"  href="property.php">Go Back </a>
</div>

<p>You haven't added any Co-owners Yet.</p>

//My form starts from here//

<h2>Owner Property details</h2>
<input  type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'>
<p><label for="name_coowner">Coowner Name</label> <input id="name_coowner" type="text"    name="name_coowner"  /></p>
<p><label for="pan_coowner">PAN Of Coowner</label> <input id="pan_coowner" type="text"   name="pan_coowner"  /></p>
```

If i open the page iam getting this form but in this Owner Property details should be shown only when i click on add a property owner.Remaining all other should be Hidden it should show only form thats it.

Comment: Where is your form ?

Comment: my form is starts from <h2>Owner Property Details</h2>

Comment: only this form should be shown when i click on  add remaining should be hide

Comment: You can't do this with PHP, this is a client-side event.

Comment: ya i know this is client side i need to implement that only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace your code with this:

Note:** This requires a working internet connection for fetching JQuery library over internet

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of website</title>
        <style>
            .hidden
            {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.add-property').click(function () {
                    $('.hidden').toggle('slow');
                    $('#add-owner-div').addClass('hidden');
                    $('#go-back-div').addClass('hidden'); 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <h2 style="font-size: 2em; margin-bottom: 0.75em; margin-left: -1%;">Specify Co-Owners for self occupied property</h2>
    <div class="last" style="margin-right: 0; padding-right: 0;">
        <div class="last" style="width: 710px;">
            <p class="narrate quiet" style="margin-left: 2%; width: 100%;margin-bottom: 0.75em;"> <b>Would you like to add Co-owner? </b></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span-12 last mt10" style="margin-top:-3%;margin-left:2%;" id="add-owner-div">
        <a class="large awesome oranges add-property"  >Add a property Co-owner</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span-12 last mt10" style="margin-top:-3%;margin-left:51%;" id="go-back-div">
        <a class="large awesome orange"  href="property.php">Go Back </a>
    </div>
    <p>You haven't added any Co-owners Yet.</p>
    <h2>Owner Property details</h2>
    <div class="hidden" style="display:none">
        <form>
            <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'>
            <p><label for="name_coowner">Coowner Name</label> <input id="name_coowner" type="text"    name="name_coowner"  /></p>
            <p><label for="pan_coowner">PAN Of Coowner</label> <input id="pan_coowner" type="text"   name="pan_coowner"  /></p>  
        </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

If you have any other css libraries or bootstrap you can include in head tag
PHP is not an option to do this. If you want it to do with PHP dependent value you can use JQuery ajax.

Comment: Add a property co-owner is already present if i click on that then only the form should show otherwise it should not be displayed.In the above you have added Add button one more

Comment: @user5891511 now check, i have changed according to your need. Now when you click on Add a property, then form will hide or show.

Comment: <form style="display:none"> it is not working here if i add that in my html file showing as undefined attribute

Comment: @user5891511 do one thing remove style attribute and add this attribute id="hidden" And then add this in head tag of your HTML file #hidden{display:none;}

Comment: iam not getting what you are saying

Comment: @user5891511 Go through once and execute this on browser, Still if you there is any problem just let me know.. I will surely help you

Comment: it is displaying the form if i click on add but it is not that add button go back button and text

Comment: If i click on add button it should show only form, it should not show add button,go back button and text

Comment: normally it is working if i implement in my html code then it is not working showing invalid location of tag(form)

Comment: @user5891511 can you please edit your post with your html code..?

Comment: sahil can you lease update the previous one which you have added with out <div class="hidden"> i will check once

Answer (score 0):

Your add button should be like this

```
<a class="large awesome oranges"  id="add_btn">Add a property Co-owner</a>
```

Put your form elements inside form

```
<form nam="myform" id="myform"  style="display:none">

<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name='email'> <p><label for="name_coowner">Coowner Name</label> <input id="name_coowner" type="text" name="name_coowner" ></p> <p><label for="pan_coowner">PAN Of Coowner</label> <input id="pan_coowner" type="text" name="pan_coowner" ></p></form>
```

Js:

```
$("#add_btn").on('click',function(){

$("#myform").show();
}
```

Comment: if i give form then it is showing invalid location of tag

Comment: Which tag r u talking?

Comment: if i add <form id="myform" style="display:none" it will show as invalid location of tag

Comment: Your form contains invalid HTML syntax

Comment: getting same as invalid location of tag(Form)